# sugarcrm mobile sdk android_assets/www/index.html missing

Tags: android, sugarcrm

I am new SugarCrm mobile sdk.
I installed android studio on ubuntu along with mobile sdk from sugarCrm,
When I create a sample project using

```
"$SUGAR_MOBILE_SDK_HOME/6.1.1.452-1.3.0-2/sdk/generate-app"
```

I gives no error & create platforms for native android & ios
& than import it in android studio.
On launching  app it give error android_assets/www/index.html missing.
When I see it in asstes/www folder, it never created.

Did I miss something or what?

Answer (score 0):

Had to run following command at app's root path to generate index.html along with other required files.

```
./sdk build --scheme debug --platform android --init-native
```

Now its working